# It's Python3-Wifi library error mistake?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, network-programming, python-3.6

I try to use module python3-wifi like python-wifi but it's python3 version for get current wifi-ssid and Mac Address but this error i got:

**This code i'm trying**

```
from pythonwifi.iwlibs import Wireless
wifi = Wireless("wlp3s0")
wifi.getEssid() #wifi-ssid
wifi.getAPaddr() #mac address
```

python3-wifi module i try : https://github.com/llazzaro/python3-wifi

**This Error I got**

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pythonwifi/iwlibs.py", line 278, in getEssid
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pythonwifi/iwlibs.py", line 789, in getEssid
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pythonwifi/iwlibs.py", line 1220, in __init__
TypeError: cannot use a str to initialize an array with typecode 'c'
```

It's module error mistake? because i follow code from module correctly and if is module mistake, can someone tell me what module should i can use like get current ssid,mac,ip, and gateway? Thanks before...

Answer (score 1):

It is an error in the linked module. The 'c' flag was apparently removed from the 'array' class. Comparing the docs from [python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/array.html) with the ones for [python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/array.html) there no longer is a `'c'` flag for `char`, only `b` and `B` remain.

Looking at the linked github's [commit history](https://github.com/llazzaro/python3-wifi/commits/master) indicates that the code was cloned from somewhere else, renamed from `python-wifi` to `python3-wifi` without any significant changes and then never touched again (since 2 years), so the code is probably just not completely ported. You can try [opening an issue](https://github.com/llazzaro/python3-wifi/issues) or fixing the code yourself, maybe it already works when you replace the `c` with `B` in `"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pythonwifi/iwlibs.py", line 1220, in __init__`

Comment: I try to replace the c with B but error still there, can you recommend me the library like python3-wifi in python3?

Comment: Adressing that part requires more knowledge on what you are trying to achieve in the end. Care to elaborate by adding it to your question?